# Too much space in my table

Tags: php, html, class, html-table

I have a little problem with my PHP code for a table filled with some of my database content. I tried to separate every registration from table in a div. What can I do to get rid of that space visible on the second and third registration div?

**Table example:**

[image: Table example]

```html
<?php
$selected = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM lucrari, editors");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selected)){
    echo '<div class="lucrare">';
    echo '<table class="tabel_lucrari">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th><div class="titlu_lucrare"><a href="lucrare.php?id_lucrare='.$row['id_lucrare'].'"'.'>'.$row['titlu'].'</a></div></th>';
    echo '<th></th>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td rowspan="3">'.'<img src="'.$row['avatar'].'">'.'</td>';
    echo '<td><div class="text_lucrare">Autor:&nbsp;</div>'.$row['autor'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><div class="text_lucrare">Disciplina:&nbsp;</div>'.$row['disciplina'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.'<div class="text_lucrare">Data postarii:&nbsp;</div>'.$row['data'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: could you show us the rendered html+css?...

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML (not the PHP) and your existing CSS in the snippet. If you click on the "Run code snippet", you'll see nothing happens.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I can't do this. I attached an image to show my code "in action".

Comment: `title` is resizing your `td` put `colspan` on `th` tag

Comment: @CatalinAvasiloaie inspect from broswer

Comment: Why can't you posted the rendered HTML? Most people complain that they can't post the PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

White space is caused because the width of your `th` tag is bigger than `td` where your `avatar` is. Therefore it resizes whole column.

If you add  `colspan` to `th` element it should be fine.

```
<th colspan="2"><div class="titlu_lucrare">
  <a href="lucrare.php?id_lucrare='.$row['id_lucrare'].'"'.'>'.$row['titlu'].'</a></div>
</th>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you talking about the space between each table do this:

Remove the `echo '<br>';` at the end.

if you still have the space try the following:
add CSS

```
.lucrare {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Updated: I see your problem with the table title expanded, you could always use this css to debug then remove it once you done:

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

By doing this you could easily see the problem. use `colspan="2"` and sometime you might need to remove the empty `<th></th>` if you have a border.

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="lucrare">
  <table class="tabel_lucrari">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="titlu_lucrare"><a href="lucrare.php?id_lucrare='.$row['id_lucrare'].'" '.'>'.$row['titlu'].'</a></div>
      </th>
      <th></th>
      <tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3">'.'<img src="'.$row['avatar'].'">'.'</td>
          <td>
            <div class="text_lucrare">Autor:&nbsp;</div>'.$row['autor'].'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="text_lucrare">Disciplina:&nbsp;</div>'.$row['disciplina'].'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="text_lucrare">Data postarii:&nbsp;</div>'.$row['data'].'</td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br>

<div class="lucrare">
  <table class="tabel_lucrari">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="titlu_lucrare"><a href="lucrare.php?id_lucrare='.$row['id_lucrare'].'" '.'>This Title is too long...Sorry!</a></div>
      </th>
      <th></th>
      <tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3">'.'<img src="'.$row['avatar'].'">'.'</td>
          <td>
            <div class="text_lucrare">Autor:&nbsp;</div>'.$row['autor'].'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="text_lucrare">Disciplina:&nbsp;</div>'.$row['disciplina'].'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="text_lucrare">Data postarii:&nbsp;</div>'.$row['data'].'</td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br>
<div class="lucrare">
  <table class="tabel_lucrari">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">
        <div class="titlu_lucrare"><a href="lucrare.php?id_lucrare='.$row['id_lucrare'].'" '.'>This title is long too but use colspan can fix</a></div>
      </th>
      <tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3">'.'<img src="'.$row['avatar'].'">'.'</td>
          <td>
            <div class="text_lucrare">Autor:&nbsp;</div>'.$row['autor'].'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="text_lucrare">Disciplina:&nbsp;</div>'.$row['disciplina'].'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="text_lucrare">Data postarii:&nbsp;</div>'.$row['data'].'</td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br>
```